# Setting no of textarea column equal to width of the container/table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to set the width of the textarea tag exactly equal to that of the table.is there any way to achieve this.

```
<table width="60%">
<tr>
<td>
<textarea name="reply_comment" id="reply_comment" cols="90"  rows="1"  width="100%"   placeholder="Type your comment here...." required></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `cols` depends on the current font. If you want it based on the parent, try CSS: [`width: 100%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Could you please provide this as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this within the textarea tag : style="width:100%"

It should take the width of the parent cell (td).